# Need to edit Moment in Antd Datepicker to display full name of month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, antd

I'm using the DatePicker component from Antd and I'm trying to edit the Moment function responsible for handling the month name.

As of now my component displays the shortened name, but I'm trying to change it to `MMMM` format so that the full name of the month displays.

Does anyone know how to do this and if this is possible at the component level?

[image: Edit goofy-currying-csgtr]

`My Component`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker, Row, Col } from "antd";

function onChange(value, dateString) {
  console.log("Selected Time: ", value);
  console.log("Formatted Selected Time: ", dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
  console.log("onOk: ", value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Row>
      <Col span={8}>
        <DatePicker
          open
          className="my-class"
          onChange={onChange}
          onOk={onOk}
          format="MMMM"
        />
      </Col>
      <Col span={2} offset={6}>
        <input value={null} />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, `DatePicker` `format` property refers to formatting the picker placeholder, not the inner dropdown title.

```
// Formats the date placeholder
<DatePicker onChange={onChange} onOk={onOk} format={'YYYY-MMMM-DD'} />
```

[image]

The closest solution is to implement your picker and render `Calendar` header as you like.

From the [official example for customizing `Calendar` header](https://codesandbox.io/s/3c7ju), you can change the month presentation:

```js
// From
months.push(localeData.monthsShort(current));
// To
months.push(localeData.months(current))
```

Check out the [examples](https://rc3dw.codesandbox.io/).

[image: Edit Q-56958116-DatePickerMonthFormat]

Comment: Yeah looks that way. I decided to go with [React DatePicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-52) instead, waaaaay more flexible